# How to convert input - 999,99 to 999.99 in Impala and Hive

Tags: hive, impala

Can anyone please let me know how to convert input 999,99 to 999.99 in Impala and Hive. Few inputs have',' which is in different position.

Comment: Sounds like a localization issue, where `999,99` in (for example) France would mean the same thing as `999.99` in the US. I would attempt to handle this in your application layer, before the input reaches the database. However, most RDBMS do support some form of a `FORMAT` function which will format the numbers accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

pls use reg replace to replace the comma with dot and then cast to decimal.

```
select cast(regexp_replace('999,99', ',', '.') as decimal(7,3))
```